# GAE get user age

Tags: google-app-engine

My app requires to know the user's age. It would be better to fetch it from the user's Google Account than to prompt the user.

I am using the Users API with Google Accounts

```
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    String email = user.getEmail();
```

Is there a similar way I can get the user's Date of Birth?

Comment: Yes, the google+ api. Not the users api. Read some docs

Answer (score 1):

No because User does not contain that information.

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User